# AS2 find Instance name

Tags: flash, actionscript, instance, actionscript-2

Is there a way in Actionscript 2 to get the name of an instance at an specific position?
I have several instances with different names and I want to store the name of an instance at a given position.
Having every instance in an array and checking the entire array in a for loop works, however it is too slow for this purpose.

Comment: I believe the `_name` property does this.

Comment: @Marty _name will give me the name of a known instance, i need to find what instance is at a specific position, there might not even be an instance there.

Comment: When you say `specific position` I'm assuming X/Y coordinates, if so, you can `hitTest` your instances by coords (or object)... But you are still going to have to loop through all your display objects that could move into that coordinate area...